# Flag Sprites css library: why it renders badly?

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I want to use a lot of flags images in a website without loading too heavy images, I found a css sprite of all flags https://www.flag-sprites.com/ , it seems very usefull so I try to use it , it works partially but it shows ugly img in chrome and firefox:

I have a folder with my index.html and fil from library flags.css and flags.png

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test sprite flag</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flags.css" />
</head> 
<body>
     <img class="flag flag-cz" alt=" Tchèque" /> 
     <img src="blank.gif" class="flag flag-cz" alt=" Tchèque" />     
     Tchèque     
     <br/>
      <img class="flag flag-zanzibar" alt=" zanzibar" /> 
     <img src="blank.gif" class="flag flag-zanzibar" alt=" zanzibar" /> 
     Zanzibar   
</body> 
</html>
```

I render well in IE but

it renders in google chrome like:

[image]

ir renders even worse in firefox:

[image]

Comment: We'd need the CSS to go along with that...probably a link to the image too.

Comment: As @Paulie_D says will need all the code required to replicate the issue to be able to give you a hand. On the face of it though it looks like you are using the `img` tags in an odd way (e.g. the `src` attribute is mandatory https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `<img>` tag for the sprite. you'd better do it like this:

```
<div class="flag flag-cz"><div>
```

And in your CSS file:

```
.flag{
    background-image: url( "Adress/the/flag/file.png" );
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 32px;        /* width of each country flag */
    height: 32px;       /* height of each country flag */
}
.flag-cz{
    background-position: -32px -32px;       /* position of topmost leftmost pixel of Czech Republic flag in this example */
}
```